# BindingContext doesn't access getters in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a viewModel, which links to a view with a BindingContext.

```
BindingContext = viewModelTest;
```

within my ViewModel i have made a custom getter, with the purpose of getting a list of test items.

```
public class viewModelTest: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<string> partners
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> _partners = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test3" };
            return _partners;
        }
    }
    public List<string> partnersTwo
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> _partners2 = new List<string>() { "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7" };
            return _partners;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the following xaml:

```
<CarouselView>
    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout/>
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame>
                            <Label Text="{Binding partners}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding partnersTwo}"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

From the above code, i'm not able to access my getter `{Binding partners}`

It is only possible if I change my BindingContext to the following:

```
BindingContext = viewModelTest.partners;
```

This is naturally undesired, as i want to be able to pass multiple parameters to my view, i.e. partnersTwo.

Therefore, how can i make individual bindings in my xaml file, from my ViewModelTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `model` and binding all value of control (such as text of label or backgroundcolor of button) to the property of it.

#### xaml

```
<CarouselView ItemSource="{Binding MyItems}">
   <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout/>
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Subtitle}"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

#### code behind

```
public class ViewModelTest : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public ObservableCollection<Model> MyItems { get; set; }

   public ViewModelTest()
   {
      MyItems = new ObservableCollection<Model>() {

         new Model(){Title="Test1" ,Subtitle="Test6" },
         new Model(){Title="Test2" ,Subtitle="Test7" },
         new Model(){Title="Test3" ,Subtitle="Test8" },
         new Model(){Title="Test4" ,Subtitle="Test9" },
         new Model(){Title="Test5" ,Subtitle="Test10" },
     };
    }
}

public class Model
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Subtitle { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<CarouselView ItemSource="{Binding partners}">
    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout/>
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame>
                            <Label Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Comment: It works, but what if i have another property in my viewModel that i want to access in another label?

Comment: In that case create a class mode having two public string properties say, Label1 and Label2. And then bind them as `<Label Text="{Binding Label1}"/>` and `<Label Text="{Binding Label2}"/>` .

Comment: @Avacay Label is an content holder which can hold single content. As your data models if you want to display all items as seperate you need list of labels

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary when i have a `DataTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Label="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=myPage}, Path=BindingContext.DataContext.partners}"
```

Where: `myPage` is the Name of your Page (yes, you need to name your page)

Only sidenote here: Text Property is of type 'string'. You're returning a list of strings. Consider converting the list of strings into one single string and return it to the property...